# autoscale a crate cluster

Tags: autoscaling, crate, rancher

I'm playing around deploying crate in a Rancher environment.

It's working fine, but I have issues with two config params:

gateway.expected_nodes and gateway.recover_after_nodes.

What is best practice regarding these two when it comes to scaling crate up and down.

/hw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The settings `gateway.expected_nodes` and `gateway.recover_after_nodes` are
only relevant *during* node startup.

- scale-down: After you've removed some nodes you *should* update the configuration
  to reflect the new number of nodes in the cluster. But you *don't need* to
  restart.
- scale-up: You should change the settings to the number of nodes you're going
  to have. This should be done *before* you start those new nodes.
  But you *don't need* to restart the existing nodes.

For a running node/cluster these values don't have any effect at all, that's why you don't necessarily have to restart (but the values should be correct in case you *do* restart them). They're
only relevant during start-up. They control if the node (that is just starting)
should recover the data from it's filesystem or if it should wait for other
nodes in the cluster and receive the data from them.

For example given the case that you've 2 nodes: N1 and N2.

- You create a table
- You stop N2
- You delete the table (on N1)
- You start N2
- N2 reads the gateway settings - it's wrong so it thinks it's going to be the only node in the cluster and recovers the table because it doesn't know that it got deleted on N1 (it doesn't know about N1 *yet*)
- N2 eventually joins N1
- The table is back in the cluster

**update**

> should I care about warning in admin when all nodes being started or restarted will have correct settings

If they will have the correct settings on a (re)start the warnings can be ignored.

Comment: Also important to note ist that those settings do not only affect how user data is loaded, but also metadata (which means also persistent dynamic settings). So those gateways settings are required to be set in the configuration files of the nodes.

Comment: Ok, and thanks. I take, it since any new node (and nodes that restarts) in my crate-docker image will have updates values for these opts, I will not have an issue and the warnings in create admin is not severe?

Scale down: as far as I've read, these opts cannot be set via admin gui. So any updates require restart(?)
But then again, probably not a severe warning?

Bottom line is: should I care about warning in admin when all nodes being started or restarted will have correct settings?